# Supressing the header from printing for pytest

Tags: python, testing, printing, pytest

How do I suppress the header (~4 lines) from printing?

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.3, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /sandboxes/beetle, inifile:
collecting ... collected 1 item
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--no-header` option was added in `pytest` 6.0: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/changelog.html#id33

Answer (score 0):

Running pytest with the -q option will suppress the header (but possibly other information as well)

[pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html?highlight=quiet#asserting-that-a-certain-exception-is-raised)

Comment: I knew that already. But I am looking to suppress the header alone.